# Sequelize - Join varchar and varchar array

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to convert the following PostgreSQL query to Sequelize:

```
select reviews.product_id, products.brand
  from reviews inner join products 
  on reviews.product_id = any(products.product_id);
```

`reviews.product_id` is a varchar and `products.product_id` is a varchar array, which is why I am using the `any` operator. I created this Sequelize query to try to replicate the query above, but it just returns an empty object.

```
db.reviews.findAll({
  attributes: ["product_id"],
  include: [{
    model: db.products,
    as: "products",
    on: {
      col1: where(col("reviews.product_id"), "=", {[Op.contains]: [col("products.product_id")]})
    },
    required: true,
    attributes: ["brand"]
  }],
  limit: 10
})
  .then(reviews => res.json(reviews))
  .catch(err => res.json(err));
```

The PostgreSQL query works as expect, so I know it should be returning something. For context, I have set up the following belongsTo association in my `reviews` model:

```
myModel.associate = models => {
  myModel.belongsTo(models.products, {foreignKey: "product_id", targetKey: "product_id", as: "products"});
};
```

I don't know how I can accurately specify that I am joining on different types (varchar and varchar array) to get the results I want. Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I was using the wrong operator. I just changed the `on` argument in `include` from:

```
on: {
  col1: where(col("reviews.product_id"), "=", {[Op.contains]: [col("products.product_id")]})
}
```

to:

```
on: {
  col1: where(col("reviews.product_id"), "=", {[Op.any]: [col("products.product_id")]})
}
```